# Prove orthornormal set is a basis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

> Suppose that $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal subset of Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ is a dense subset of $\mathcal{H}$.
>   Show $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$ if
>   $||f||_\mathcal{H}^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle f\mid u_n\rangle|^2$ for all $f\in \mathcal{S}$

Attempt:
Let $h\in \mathcal{H}$ is arbitrary, and $f\in\mathcal{S}$ is close to $h$
By bessel's ineq, $\sum_n |\langle h, u_n\rangle |^2\leq ||h||^2$ but I can't seem to find a lower bound for $\sum_n |\langle h, u_n\rangle|^2$ using $f$

I'm not sure how to translate closeness between $f,h$ to closeness between $|\langle f,u_n\rangle|, |\langle h,u_n\rangle|$

Comment: If the equation is true for all f, then we can take f to be some u_i and see the set u_i are orthonormal. Let V be the space spanned by these u_i, I think u can conclude that the closure of this space is the entire space by using the equation given.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net 
I've added some thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by DisintegratingByParts is perfectly fine, but maybe this is more elementary.

An orthonormal set is an orthonormal basis if it is spanning, i.e., its span is dense. Assume your sequence $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is not spanning, then there exists $y \neq 0$ in the orthogonal complement of the closure of the span of $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$.

Let $(y_m)_{m\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $S$ converging to $y$ (exists due to density) then you have that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $M\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $m \geq M$:
$$
\|y\|^2 -\epsilon \leq  \|y_m \|^2 =   \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} | \langle y_m, u_n \rangle|^2 \leq 2\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} | \langle y_m - y, u_n \rangle|^2 + 2\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} | \langle y, u_n \rangle|^2 \leq 2\|y_m - y\|^2 \to 0, \text{ for } m \to \infty,
$$
where the last estimate follows by the Bessel inequality and the orthogonality of $y$ on all $u_n$. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we get that $y = 0$. A contradiction. Hence $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is spanning and thus an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was looking for.
I apologize if my response to DisintegratingByParts came off off-putting.

Comment: Actually, how did you obtain $|\langle y_m, u_n\rangle|^2 = |\langle y_m-y, u_n\rangle + \langle y, u_n\rangle|^2\leq |\langle y_m - y, u_n\rangle|^2+|\langle y, u_n\rangle |^2$?
does the triangle inequality hold for $|\cdot|^2$

Comment: It does not, I missed a factor of two there. Thanks. I updated my answer. You have that $(a+b)^2 \leq 2a^2 + 2b^2$

Answer (score 1):

If $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal subset of a Hilbert space $H$, then Parseval's equality holds for some $x\in H$ iff $x$ is in the closed linear span $\mathcal{U}$ of $\{ u_n \}$. So, if a subspace $\mathcal{S}$ is contained in $\mathcal{U}$, then so its closure $\mathcal{S}^c$; and if $\mathcal{S}$ is dense, then Parseval's equality holds for all $x\in H$, which means $\{ u_n \}$ is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: I think the problem is asking to prove this fact.
This isn't something that was explicitly mentioned in my class.